# First rational cohomology of covering space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

It is well known that for a finite covering space of topological spaces we get an injection of the fundamental group to the base space with finite index. It is also well known that the first cohomology is the dual of the fundamental group. I was wondering whether there is a example for the following statement:

- A finite covering space map $X\rightarrow Y$ such that $H^1(Y, \mathbb{Q})$ is not isomorphic to $H^1(X, \mathbb{Q})$ under pullback.

Comment: In other words, the question is as follows: let $H\leq G$ be a finite index subgroup. Is $H^{ab} \otimes \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow G^{ab} \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ an isomorphism? I think that it’s surjective (if $g \in G$, one of its powers is in $H$).

Comment: Yes it is injective, but I think it won't be an isomorphism although I can't find a counter-example.

Comment: (The previous version was about the transfer map $G^{ab} \rightarrow H^{ab}$ supposedly showing that $H^{ab} \rightarrow G^{ab}$ was injective after tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ – which would prove the claim. But I’m not so sure now…)

Comment: How about $H$ being the infinite cyclic group with generator $a$ and $G=\langle H,b\rangle$ where $b^2=e$, $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$? Then $H$ is abelian infinite but $G^{ab}$ is finite…

Comment: I think it works thanks.

Comment: There are many examples with $X$ and $Y$ surfaces. I encourage you to find some.